# Fastlane Screenshots are not saved but also throws no error

Tags: xcode, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

I am new to Fastline and wanted to setup the automatic screenshots, but I keep getting no error, but also no screenshot. The only noticeable Output is:

```
+------------------------------+
|       snapshot results       |
+----------------------+-------+
| Device               | en-US |
+----------------------+-------+
| iPhone 15 Pro Max    |  ❌   |
| iPad Pro (12.9-inch) |  ❌   |
+----------------------+-------+
```

there are also a few warnings but they are all about implicit conversion of integers and deprecated functions.

here is the summary output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             Summary for snapshot 2.216.0                              |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
| scheme                               | captureScreenshot                              |
| project                              | ./ear2brain.xcodeproj                          |
| devices                              | ["iPhone 15 Pro Max", "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)"]  |
| languages                            | ["en-US"]                                      |
| launch_arguments                     | [""]                                           |
| output_directory                     | /Users/hannesnagel/Documents/ear2brain/e2b/fa  |
|                                      | stlane/screenshots                             |
| output_simulator_logs                | false                                          |
| skip_open_summary                    | false                                          |
| skip_helper_version_check            | false                                          |
| clear_previous_screenshots           | false                                          |
| reinstall_app                        | false                                          |
| erase_simulator                      | false                                          |
| headless                             | true                                           |
| override_status_bar                  | false                                          |
| localize_simulator                   | false                                          |
| app_identifier                       | com.nagel.e2b                                  |
| buildlog_path                        | ~/Library/Logs/snapshot                        |
| clean                                | false                                          |
| number_of_retries                    | 1                                              |
| stop_after_first_error               | false                                          |
| result_bundle                        | false                                          |
| concurrent_simulators                | true                                           |
| disable_slide_to_type                | false                                          |
| skip_package_dependencies_resolution | false                                          |
| disable_package_automatic_updates    | false                                          |
| xcodebuild_formatter                 | xcbeautify                                     |
| use_system_scm                       | false                                          |
| xcode_path                           | /Applications/Xcode.app                        |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried this with `fastlane init` and `fastlane init swift`but both do not work.

I am using an M1 MacBook Pro (from 2020) with MacOS 14.0, Xcode 15 and Xcode command line tools for Xcode 15

Comment: Did you try to run it with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: Yes I tried that but I  have  right now with a different project and it worked. I now deleted and cloned my project again and it works now. It produces screenshots.

Comment: But why didn't it work and works after recloning the project? I cleaned build folder, ... before and it did not help.